# How to mask shiny application url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shiny, url-masking

I have a ruby on rails application with third party oauth enabled and I have used shiny server to render shiny application from ec2 instance, currently I used iframe to render shiny application but I don't to expose shiny application url

Is there any to mask shiny application url from client side?